# Submitting Formik form in React Native

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, formik

I am building a React Native app that uses Formik. When I submit the form I call `handleSubmit`

```
<Formik
  onSubmit={values => {
    handleSubmit(values)
  }}>
```

I define this before the `return` on my form:

```
const handleSubmit = (values) => {
  const { status, data } = usePostRequest("/api/holidays-request", {
    dateFrom: "2023-02-01",
    dateTo: "2023-02-28",
    fromHalf: 0,
    toHalf: 0,
  });
};
```

I have hard coded some values here for testing.

My `usePostRequest` is a custom hook I wrote to actually send the data to my API.

When I submit my form then `handleSubmit` is triggered but I get an erorr:

> Warning: An unhandled error was caught from submitForm() [Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
>
> 1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
> 2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
> 3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app

It must be reason 2 that I am failing but I am unsure how to use my `usePostRequest` to submit the values from the form.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you take a look at the [custom hooks documentation](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/reusing-logic-with-custom-hooks#when-to-use-custom-hooks)

In this particular case you should write the post logic as a function and use it here directly.

Answer (score 0):

Do not call hooks in event handlers.

```
const handleSubmit = (values) => {
  const { status, data } = usePostRequest("/api/holidays-request", {
    dateFrom: "2023-02-01",
    dateTo: "2023-02-28",
    fromHalf: 0,
    toHalf: 0,
  });
};
```

See [Invalid Hook Call Warning](https://reactjs.org/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning.html) for details.